# Movesense iOS API: devices disconnecting automatically

Tags: movesense

device firmware is custom based on 1.7.2
ios app is using the 1.28.1 cocoapod for Movesense.

app can see the device connect to it, and query the battery status.  This all works fine, but a lot of times, after the battery status is queried, the device disconnects automatically, as seen via the response to MDS/ConnectedDevices, and on the device itself via debug logs:

    `Subscribed and listening for notifications. Press ESC to stop:
    TODO not thoroughly tested
    @6708 { {
    "Timestamp": 5124990,
    "Level": [
    4,
    "Verbose"
    ],
    "Tag": "",
    "Message": "BatteryChargeProvider::stoponGetRequest timeDiff: 51713"
    } }
    @6898 { {
    "Timestamp": 5125142,
    "Level": [
     4,
    "Verbose"
    ],
    "Tag": "",
    "Message": "Disconnect(const Address& rAddress) called"
     } }
    /Users/builduser/buildAgent/work/a29f59699a429e89/src/whiteboard  /comm/internal/serial/SerialAdapter.cpp(246): ASSERT FAILED! [bufferData == TotalHeaderSize]
    [1]    73425 abort      wbcmd --port /dev/cu.usbserial-AI04RYMP     SUBSCRIBESystem/Debug/4`

and from the app debug:

```
Disconnected device: <MDSEvent at 0x282903300: header: {
"Content-Length" = 122;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Uri = "MDS/EventListener/23";
}
bodyDictionary: {
Body =     {
    Serial = 175030000645;
};
Method = DEL;
Response =     {
    Status = 200;
};
Uri = "suunto://MDS/ConnectedDevices";
}
0x282903300>
```

is anyone else seeing this?  It happens randomly but frequently, and whether I'm connecting to one or multiple devices, makes no difference.  When multiple devices are used, it happen to one at random.  It will occur multiple times in a row: connect, get battery, disconnect, find the device, connect, get battery, disconnect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the sensor resets when the disconnect happens (reset causes a disconnect)? Have you tried looking at the faultcom_GetLastFaultStr() to see if the sensor has encountered an error when the disconnect has happened? Alternative would be a low-battery which can cause a sensor reset when battery is measured (battery measurement is a power intensive 1-2mA operation).

Comment: We've run some tests here with iPhone with iOS Showcase app (MDS 1.28.1) against hr_wakeup_app 1.7.2 and have not been able to reproduce the issue. My guess is either an error in your sensor app or low battery: either one can cause disconnect via reset of the sensor.

If you have a jig it would be good to run the sensor on the Jig and log the debug messages to file using JLinkRTTViewer. From that log the reset and the reset reason is easily recognized.